# How to discover if a specific address/port is reachable?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-xp, port

I need a **simple utility** that allow me to check if a PC, attached to a local network, is able to reach a specified **address:port** using specified **protocol like TCP or UDP**

Machine's OS I will use to do the check is Windows XP.

Comment: You should check our psexec from Microsoft Sysinternals. It will allow you to run a process on a given computer using given credentials.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use simply `telnet`:

```
telnet hostname port
```

If you get a connection, something replies on that port.

If you get an error message, no program is listening on that port, or the hostname is invalid:

```
Connecting To hostname...Could not open connection to the 
host, on port <port>: Connect failed
```

Comment: +1, telnet or the allmighty netcat (nc), but you have to grab that from "somewhere", so telnet is just fine.

Comment: @snark which protocol is used to do this test? TCP, UDP or other?

Comment: TCP is used, as telnet establishes a connection. UDP is connectionless so you cannot tell if someone is listening or not.

Comment: thanks. So there is no way to use a tool to check if UDP is allowed in output on a certain port? Only using the desired application and see it is working?

Answer (score 3):

[nmap](http://nmap.org/download.html) should be able to handle this.

Comment: if you could provide an example along with this suggestion, that would be great. Maybe something like this would work: `nmap -v IP_ADDRESS -Pn -p PORT`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [iperf](http://iperf.fr) to check if UDP ports are reachable or not.

Example: Testing if port 5093 UDP is open on remote server 10.0.0.1

```
C:\>iperf -u -p 5093 -c 10.0.0.1
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to 10.0.0.1, UDP port 5093
Sending 1470 byte datagrams
UDP buffer size: 8.00 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[320] local 10.16.61.182 port 54574 connected with 10.0.0.1 port 5093
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[320]  0.0-10.0 sec  1.25 MBytes  1.05 Mbits/sec
[320] **Sent 893 datagrams**
```

As you can see the client successfully transferred 893 datagrams meaning the port is open indeed. In case the firewall was blocking the port, you should read a message like this:

```
Read failed: Connection reset by peer
```